# How to handle/fix android.os.DeadObjectException in Android TextToSpeech

Tags: java, android, flutter, text-to-speech, flutter-plugin

I am encountering a crash in my Flutter app related to a custom Flutter plugin that handles Text-to-Speech functionality on the Android side. Specifically, after the app has been running for approximately 30 minutes, the following issue occurs.

```
android.os.DeadObjectException
  at android.os.BinderProxy.transactNative(Native Method)
  at android.os.BinderProxy.transact(BinderProxy.java:571)
  at android.speech.tts.ITextToSpeechService$Stub$Proxy.isLanguageAvailable(ITextToSpeechService.java:919)
  at android.speech.tts.TextToSpeech.lambda$isLanguageAvailable$16(TextToSpeech.java:1842)
  at android.speech.tts.TextToSpeech$$ExternalSyntheticLambda11.run(Unknown Source:2)
  at android.speech.tts.TextToSpeech$Connection.runAction(TextToSpeech.java:2361)
  at android.speech.tts.TextToSpeech.runAction(TextToSpeech.java:813)
  at android.speech.tts.TextToSpeech.runAction(TextToSpeech.java:803)
  at android.speech.tts.TextToSpeech.isLanguageAvailable(TextToSpeech.java:1825)
  at com.custom.my_audio_plugin.helpers.VoiceAssistant.isLanguageAvailable(VoiceAssistant.java:177)
  at com.custom.my_audio_plugin.MyAudioMapper.isLanguageAvailable(MyAudioMapper.java:358)
  at com.custom.my_audio_plugin.AudioMapperPlugin.onMethodCall(AudioMapperPlugin.java:150)
  at io.flutter.plugin.common.MethodChannel$IncomingMethodCallHandler.onMessage(MethodChannel.java:258)
  at io.flutter.embedding.engine.dart.DartMessenger.invokeHandler(DartMessenger.java:295)
  at io.flutter.embedding.engine.dart.DartMessenger.lambda$dispatchMessageToQueue$0$DartMessenger(DartMessenger.java:322)
  at io.flutter.embedding.engine.dart.-$$Lambda$DartMessenger$2j2MERcK825A5j1fv5sZ7xB2Iuo.run(Unknown Source:12)
  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
  at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:201)
  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:288)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7839)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
  at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:548)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1003)
```

I have confirmed that the `TtsEngine` is properly initialized, and I receive the expected callbacks in the `TextToSpeech.OnInitListener` with a status of `TextToSpeech.SUCCESS`. Additionally, I have ensured that the `ActivityAware.onDetachedFromActivity()` and `FlutterPlugin.onDetachedFromEngine()` methods are not invoked during this time period.

After this crash I get below logs.

```
I/TextToSpeech(19748): Sucessfully bound to com.google.android.tts
I/TextToSpeech(19748): Connected to TTS engine
I/TextToSpeech(19748): Setting up the connection to TTS engine...
```

I would greatly appreciate any guidance or assistance in resolving or handling this issue.

Comment: I found that this ITextToSpeechService is AIDL https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/56a2301/core/java/android/speech/tts/ITextToSpeechService.aidl. 

And DeadObjectException happens when connection breaks https://developer.android.com/guide/components/aidl